# Heroku Login is Looping - Can-t login

Tags: authentication, heroku

Hi Have anybody here encountered an error where the Heroku Login page keeps on reloading on the login page over and over again after entering the (supposedly) correct credential.

I'm using Google Chrome for the web browser. It seems to me that this only occurs on Google Chrome and it is not happening on my Internet Explorer.

Computer Specification is as follows:
* Google Chrome (Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
* Internet Explorer 11
* Windows 10

Comment: I'm having the same issue with chrome version 79.0.3945.117 (64-bit). In IE works fine... has anyone encountered this recently?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your Ad-Block extension. That worked for me.

Comment: The issue has been resolved now. My team lead just asked me about this.
With regards to your answer tho. I'm not sure if it will work for somebody else.

 Thanks mate!